# How to apply a property to only one element of a UserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have created a UserControl that provides a Border panel with rounded corners and a shadow effect around all sides. It works fine except for the problem that when I set the Background brush property on an instance of the control it not only fills the inner Border element but also gets applied to the Grid so I loose the rounded corner effect.

```
    <UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Controls.RoundedPanel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         x:Name="userControl" mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <Grid Margin="-6,-5,-12,-13">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="27"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="27"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Image Height="20" Width="20" Source="../Resources/Shadow Top Left.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <Image Height="20" Grid.Column="1" Source="../Resources/Shadow Top.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <Image Height="20" Width="27" Grid.Column="2" Source="../Resources/Shadow Top Right.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <Image Width="27" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Source="../Resources/Shadow Right.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <Image Width="20" Grid.Row="1" Source="../Resources/Shadow Left.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <Image Height="27" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Source="../Resources/Shadow Bottom.png" Stretch="Fill" />
            <Image Height="27" Width="20" Grid.Row="2" Source="../Resources/Shadow Bottom Left.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <Image Height="27" Width="27" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Source="../Resources/Shadow Bottom Right.png" Stretch="Fill" Opacity="0.8" ClipToBounds="True"/>
        </Grid>
        <Border CornerRadius="12,12,12,12" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
```

I need to be able to change the Background brush of just the Border element to fill the inside of the rounded panel, different instances of the control will have different colours so I don't want the brush hard coded. The only way I can seem to achieve this is by adding a new DependencyProperty in the code behind for the control.

```
    public partial class RoundedPanel : UserControl
{
    public RoundedPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Identifies the InnerBackground dependency property. 
    /// </summary> 
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InnerBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "InnerBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(RoundedPanel));

    /// <summary> 
    /// Gets or sets the InnerBackground assigned to the control. 
    /// </summary> 
    public Brush InnerBackground
    {          
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(InnerBackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(InnerBackgroundProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Then I can bind the new property to the Border elements Background.

```
<Border CornerRadius="12,12,12,12" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{Binding InnerBackground, ElementName=userControl}" />
```

This works fine but seems a rather messy way of doing it (would be tidier to somehow be able to override the existing Background property to only apply to the Border element). Is there a better way of doing this that I am missing or is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that simply with a `RelativeSource Binding` from *inside* the `UserControl`, like this:

```
<Border CornerRadius="12" Background="{Binding InnerBackground,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:RoundedPanel}}}" />
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Oh sorry, I completely missed the last paragraph of your question.

I'm not aware of any way that you can use to stop the `UserControl` from colouring its `Background`... you *could* reuse the `Background` property like this:

```
<Border CornerRadius="12" Background="{Binding Background,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:RoundedPanel}}}" />
```

But the `UserControl` would still colour its *whole* `Background` that colour as well, so you wouldn't see it. However, *if* you had declared your control as a `CustomControl`, then you *could* have done this:

```
<Border CornerRadius="12" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
```

Please have a good read of the [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN though, *before* you think about changing the base class of your control.

Comment: Thanks for responding Sheridan. Could you elaborate a bit, I don't understand how changing to a RelativeSource can remove the need for a new DependancyProperty, which is what I'd really like to do? Or are you just referring to a cleaner way to do the binding?